# floating point:invalid error turbo C

Tags: c, runtime-error

this program takes number of columns as input and should return equivalent amount of numbers of base 3.but in tc it gives a "floating point:invalid" error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int* count(int);
main()
{
    int i,j,n,*a;

    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a=count(n);
    for(i=0;i<pow(3,n-1);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j--)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i*(n-1)+j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//calculating and storing count values in a 2d array implemented by 1d array.
int* count(int n)
{
    int i,j,*a,k;
    a=(int*)malloc((n-1)*pow(3,n-1)*sizeof(int));
    for(j=0;j<n-1;j--)
    {
        for(i=0;i<pow(3,n-1);i++)
        {  
            k=(pow(3,n-1-j));
            a[i*(n-1)+j]=i%k;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: Can you point which line of code returns this error and we can work from there.

Comment: Go and take yourself a book called K & R , Don't use turbo C , otherwise people won't have any sympathy with you here.

Comment: What is this `for(j=0;j<n-1;j--)` ?
j is going negative

Comment: without knowing the initialization values (if the variables are initialized) we can't know for sure whats going on because to me `for(j=0;j<n-1;j--)` looks like infinite loop...

Comment: 30 year old 16 bit compiler, and you're seriously trying to use that on a modern 64 bit system and expecting reliable results? And yes, learn some C as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but fixing the for loop for j won't crash.

Fix the loop at both places in your code to:

`for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)`

Answer (score 2):

At this point:

```
for(j=0;j<n-1;j--)
```

You loop over the following values:

```
0, -1, -2, -3, -4, ...
```

and the loop will (probably) terminate when `j` wraps around to a positive value. If indeed that's what happens with your long out-of-date compiler.

When you then calculate

```
pow(3,n-1-j)
```

The exponent becomes a large positive value and you will overflow in due course.

I expect that's your fundamental problem.

Comment: his fundamental problem is a fundamental lack of understanding of C. Nothing wrong with that, but in combination with using massively outdated tools and no doubt documentation (if any) it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @jwenting The program will lead to floating point overflow even on a modern compiler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hello sir,+1 actually you are right about that but the main thing is, he should start from the scratch because the way in which he is doing things could land him up in further problems and SO as we all know , knows no mercy with these folks :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, it will. Hence his fundamental lack of understanding of the language, made even worse by fearfully outdated tooling (a modern tool would likely at the very least give warnings for example).

Comment: @jwenting Now I'm agreeing with you in light of the fact that the asker accepted the answer that gave code with no explanation, over the answer that explained why the existing code failed. That usually indicates that the asker is not interested in understanding and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it seems you have not linked the math library while compiling your code.

Comment: Are you using the correct syntax according to prototype of `pow` function. See `math.h` for the prototype.